# DataGrid muestra lineas rojas

Tags: c#, .net

Al finalizar una carga de información el `DataGrid` me muestra unas lineas rojas.

Me pueden ayudar!!!?

[image: DataGrid con líneas rojas]

Comment: pareciera que el control perdio la referencia al componente, que pasa si seleccionas la seccion en lineas rojas y la eliminas. Luego vuelve agregar el grid desde la tooolbox

Comment: No puedo eliminar ya que la imagen mostrada es en modo ejecución y no diseño!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Si es un tema en la cantidad de registros podrias limitar la cantidad de lineas que lees del archivo, quizas itera por 20 o 30 y deja de hacerlo para ver si esto se muestra en el grid. O usar un archivo de monos registros para validar si es un problema con el volumnen de datos que cargas

Tambien podrias definir el grid para que trabaje en [VirtualMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.90).aspx)

en el link comenta:

> El modo virtual está diseñado para grandes almacenes de datos

[Tutorial: Implementar el modo virtual en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/15a31akc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yo he hecho prueba cargando matrices de 90,000 registros por 6 columnas y ningun problema, con un simple DataGridView con un DoubleBuffered activado. Igual voté tu respuesta Leandro por lo del Virtual Mode, que desconocía completamente. ¿Tienes idea si eso beneficia el rendimiento del grid con tantos datos?

Answer (score 0):

Eso suele indicar un problema de memoria.

Prueba a cargar menos registros. ¿Realmente tiene sentido cargar más de 50000 registros en un grid? Eso es inmanejable para el usuario.

Comment: La carga lo tengo que hacer si o si (Ya que son los registros enviados por la SUNAT - Perú)

Comment: Con respecto a la memoria, pues lo dudo ya que se probó en un servidor con 32 GB y también con un procesador de 32 núcleros

Comment: El servidor de BD utilizado es SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: ¿Pero tienes que mostrar todos de golpe? Podrías establecer algún tipo de categorización o de paginación.

Comment: La limitación de memoria puede no ser del equipo si no de la información con la que es capaz de trabajar el propio componente.

Comment: El DataGridView tiene alguna limitación?

Comment: Sobre la paginacion intentaré hacerlo a ver como me va!!!!

Comment: Luis no tiene ninguna limitación el DataGridView, como coloqué más arriba he trabajado con más datos.